# Running the tests added on a TestSuite in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm reading [Pragmatic Unit Testing in Java with JUnit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514012) and on part 3.4 it gives this code which according to the book should run. I'm confused it obviously cannot return TestSuite as a Test, is this a correction on the book? What should be the proper way to do this? (Only running the short tests)

```
import junit.framework.*;
public class TestClassTwo extends TestCase {
    public TestClassTwo(String method) {
        super(method);
    }

    // This one takes a few hours...
    public void testLongRunner() {
         TSP tsp = new TSP(); // Loard with default cities
         assertEquals(140, tsp.shortestPath(5)); // top 5
    }

    public void testAnotherShortTest() {
        TSP tsp = new TSP(); // Load with default cities
        assertEquals(586, tsp.shortestPath(10));
    }
    public static Test suite() {
         TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
         // Only include short tests
         suite.addTest( new TestClassTwo("testShortTest"));
         suite.addTest(new TestClassTwo("testAnotherShortTest"));
         return suite;
    }
}
```

So I tried running it and here's the stack trace it also gives an initializationError. If I add a cast it still gives me an initializationError.

```
  java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from TestSuite to Test
    at PracticeTest.suite(PracticeTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.SuiteMethod.testFromSuiteMethod(SuiteMethod.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.SuiteMethod.<init>(SuiteMethod.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in this book seems to be a bit old, as it's in JUnit 3.x flavor. It's not wrong, mind you - [TestSuite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) implements the `Test` interface, so it would work just fine.

However, in modern JUnit 4.x tests, the recommended way of aggregating tests in to suites is by [using the @Suite annotation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites).

Comment: I tried casting it return (Test) suite; but I'm getting an initialization error. Why is that?

Comment: No casting is needed. If you have an error, please show your code (with the failing cast) and the exception's stacktrace so we can help more easily.

Comment: Odd... Works fine for me (except for the fact that there's no method called `testShortTest`.